# Count should return only if both times are present

Tags: sql-server

I want to calculate the number of days employee was present. If he/she doesn't have timeout then it should not consider their present.

```
CREATE TABLE Attendance(
[EmpCode] INT
,[TimeIn] DATETIME
,[TimeOut] DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12,      '2018-08-01 09:00:00.000',      '2018-08-01 17:36:00.000');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12,      '2018-08-02 09:00:00.000',      NULL);
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12,      '2018-08-03 09:25:00.000',      '2018-08-03 16:56:00.000');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12,      '2018-08-04 09:13:00.000',      NULL);
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12,      '2018-08-06 09:00:00.000',      '2018-08-07 18:15:00.000');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12,      '2018-08-07 09:27:00.000',      NULL);
```

My query is returning 6 days but it should return 3 days as only 3 days have both time in and time out.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CAST(COALESCE([TimeIn], [TimeOut]) AS DATE))
FROM [dbo].[Attendance]
WHERE
CAST(COALESCE([TimeIn], [TimeOut]) AS DATE) BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-07'
```

Comment: Why is the `TimeIn` column nullable?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Attendance is being marked with device so sometime user marks  only time out and forget to mark time in and vice verca

Comment: Of, so if they have a time out but not time in, does that count as a valid attendance?

Comment: No, Both should be present in DB. I have got the help I needed. btw thank you

Comment: If both should be present than the answer you've got does not cover it. You need to change the `[TimeOut] is not null` to `COALESCE([TimeIn], [TimeOut])` is not null.

Comment: @ZoharPeled That's exactly how modified my query. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a `WHERE` condition checking for `TimeOut` is not null

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CAST(COALESCE([TimeIn], [TimeOut]) AS DATE))
FROM    
    [dbo].[Attendance]
WHERE   
    [TimeOut] is not null
and 
    CAST(COALESCE([TimeIn], [TimeOut]) AS DATE) BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-07'
```